# How to find the text width from android canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to find the height and width of text already drawn into the canvas. For finidng the height there is function:
`getTextHeight(String text,Paint paint);`
But there is no function called getTextWidth or something like that. Why is that? And what is the possible way to find the text width?

Comment: getlinewidth() function

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can measure a string that has already been drawn to the canvas, but I use

**`paint.measureText(string)`**

to determine the width of text.  Make sure to call `paint.setTypeface()` and `paint.setTextSize()` before calling the measureText method to get the accurate width.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mTextHeight;
Rect textBounds = new Rect();
paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
mTextHeight = textBounds.height();
```